# Why is sqlite3 memory database persisted to disk?

Tags: sqlite, go-sqlite3

In my go program I does this to initialize my sqlite3 schema:

```golang
db.MustExec(`ATTACH DATABASE ":memory:" AS "mem"`)
db.MustExec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mem.token" (
    "token"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "expire" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "login"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "auth"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("token")
) WITHOUT ROWID`)
```

The problem is, this table is **persisted** to disk!  After quit the program, I use sqlite3 command line tool to open the database file, the `mem.token` table is still there, if I insert data into it, the data is persisted and available even after I reboot my PC.

How to make a memory table with transient data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By quoting the database you create with:

```
db.MustExec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mem.token" (
```

You're instructing SQLite to create a database called literally `mem.token` on the current database.  If you want to create a database called `token` on the attached memory database, don't use the quotes:

```
db.MustExec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mem.token (
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.MustExec(`ATTACH DATABASE "" AS "mem"`)
```

Check `Temporary Databases` section of https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html